# Custom Listview in Android Application

Tags: java, android, listview

For some reason i can't figure out how to add a custom layout file to my list-view, I've tried nearly every tutorial out there and still I'm missing a link in this process, so that's why I turn to you guys.

I figured out so far that i need a custom adapter which extends the regular arrayadapter.

ReminderAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReminderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ReminderObject> {

    private ArrayList<ReminderObject> items;
    private Context context;

    public ReminderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ReminderObject> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.reminder_row, null);
        }
        ReminderObject o = items.get(position);
        if (o != null) {
            TextView txtTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

I also know that it's required to have an object with getters and setters for every property

```
class ReminderObject {

    int _id, _hours, _minutes;

    public ReminderObject(){}

    public ReminderObject(int _hours, int _minutes){
        this._hours = _hours;
        this._minutes = _minutes;
    }

    public ReminderObject(int id, int _hours, int _minutes){
        this._id = id;
        this._hours = _hours;
        this._minutes = _minutes;
    }

    public int getIdentifier(){
        return this._id;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    public int getHours(){
        return this._hours;
    }

    public void setHours(int hours){
        this._hours = hours;
    }

    public int getMinutes(){
        return this._minutes;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int minutes){
        this._minutes = minutes;
    }

}
```

And over here I got my custom layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/trash"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Database Handler class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class dbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "remindersDB";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "reminders";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_HOURS = "hours";
    private static final String KEY_MINUTES = "minutes";

    public dbHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_HOURS + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_MINUTES + " INTEGER" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    void addReminder(ReminderObject reminder) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_HOURS, reminder.getHours());
        values.put(KEY_MINUTES, reminder.getMinutes());
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList getAllReminders()
    {
        ArrayList reminderList = new ArrayList();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ReminderObject reminder = new ReminderObject();
                reminderList.add(cursor.getInt(1) + ":" + cursor.getInt(2));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return reminderList;
    }

    public void deleteReminder(ReminderObject reminderobject) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(reminderobject.getIdentifier()) });
        db.close();
    }

    public void deleteAllReminders() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("VACUUM");
    }

}
```

And the final method I call in my activity to fill the list

```
private void populateListView() {
        dbHandler dbConnection = new dbHandler(getApplicationContext());
        ListView lvReminders = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        List reminders = dbConnection.getAllReminders();
        ReminderAdapter adapter = new ReminderAdapter(this, R.layout.reminder_row, reminders);
        lvReminders.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

The error that causes the application to close

```
 05-05 21:32:17.506    9042-9042/nl.co.hoofdpijn E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at nl.co.hoofdpijn.ReminderAdapter.getView(ReminderAdapter.java:25)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2397)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1974)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1217)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1390)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4481)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Rule 25: LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: what's on your Reminder activity java 24 line?

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminders); @Pedro Teran

Comment: so that means that you have a ListActivity change on your layout the id of the list view to android.R.id.list using this @android:id/list

Comment: where is your listview with id `lvReminders` ?

Comment: I've changed the identifier of the list-view, thanks for that. But it still won't work. See the updated error log.

Comment: review your logic on the getView you have a variable that is null on your java line 25 of the adapter under the getView and also remember that you are not sending any information to your textview  maybe a setText() to populate the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the context is null in your case. You have the private variable 'context' but you are never assigning any value to it.

Change the constructor of the Adapter as below which should fix the NPE: 
public ReminderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList items) 
{
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

Comment: Thanks, but as soon as i change it in-to that constructor he cannot find symbol items?

Comment: The NPE is due to the reason that this.context is not assigned the value. It can find symbol items as you are passing those items to super class..

Comment: Is that answers you question..  ?